# Set image in mobile angular ui website

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mobile-angular-ui

I am implement mobile website. I am using mobileangularui framework for mobile website. I want to set image in home.html, But i could not set image from image folder.If i put URL of image which is exist in server then it is works. I will show screen shot of code snippet.
[image]

Existing output:
[image]

home.html

```
<style>
.bgImage
{
    background-image: url('http://www.electricshop.com/editordocs/image/OurTopGiftIdeas231215_978x400.png');
    height:330px;
    background-position: center center;

}
</style>
<div class="jumbtron scrollable-content">
   <div class="bgImage">
  </div>
  <img src="../images/clocks.jpg">
  <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-NFIfiFmg8SA/Ti0xrNqB4OI/AAAAAAAADno/fB_2wYQBiv4/s1600/silence-between-two-people.jpg">

</div>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>y</title>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="yes" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.min.css" />

    <script src="http://localhost:8001/target/target-script-min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style>
  .color-winni-text
  {
    color:#c62222;
  }
  </style>
  <body ng-app="Y" ng-controller="MainController">

    <!-- Sidebars -->
    <div ng-include="'sidebar.html'"
            ui-track-as-search-param='true'
            class="sidebar sidebar-left"></div>

    <div class="app">

      <!-- Navbars -->

      <div class="navbar navbar-app navbar-absolute-top">
        <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-center color-winni-text" ui-yield-to="title">
                  <strong>Winni Celebration</strong>    
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group pull-left">
          <div ui-toggle="uiSidebarLeft" class="btn sidebar-toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-bars  color-winni-text fa-2x"></i> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group pull-right" ui-yield-to="navbarAction">
          <div ui-toggle="uiSidebarRight" class="btn">
            <i class="fa fa-comment color-winni-text"></i> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar navbar-app navbar-absolute-bottom">
        <div class="btn-group justified">
          <a href="http://mobileangularui.com/" class="btn btn-navbar"><i class="fa fa-home fa-navbar"></i> Docs</a>
          <a href="https://github.com/mcasimir/mobile-angular-ui" class="btn btn-navbar"><i class="fa fa-github fa-navbar"></i> Sources</a>
          <a href="https://github.com/mcasimir/mobile-angular-ui/issues" class="btn btn-navbar"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-navbar"></i> Issues</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- App Body -->
      <div class="app-body background-color-body">
        <div class="app-content">
          <ng-view></ng-view>  
        </div>
      </div>

    </div><!-- ~ .app -->

    <div ui-yield-to="modals"></div>



  </body>
</html>
```

When i give

```
<img src="../images.clocks.jpg">
```

then it is not works, But i give image url which is exist in server then it is works.
Directory Screen Shot:
[image]
Please give me some idea.

Comment: @Shy A. It is not working.

Comment: @Shy A. I have shown directory structure in first screen shot

Comment: @Shy A. Check updated question.